# Force Sans Potential

Tags: forces, potential-energy

Is it possible to have a force without an associated potential energy? I know when a related potential energy exists, the relationship is $$U = -\int{F(x) dx}$$, but I am curious as to whether the one can exist without the other.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a non-conservative force?

Comment: Yes. I had to word my question as it is for Stack Exchange to allow me to post it.

Comment: Are you then asking if there is a least one non-conservative force that exists?

Comment: Perhaps another way to frame my question is: Do all non-conservative forces have a potential? I know they don't have one that follows the posted equation, but for instance B has a vector potential.

Comment: John Miller, a scalar potential is associated with a potential *energy*.  A vector potential is associated with a [potential *momentum*](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9803023) so it isn't actually another way to frame your question *"Is it possible to have a force without an associated potential energy"*

Comment: Okay, but we still haven't answered whether all forces have an associated potential energy, whether conservative or non-conservative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of potential energy in the framework of classical mechanics and gravitation, then yes. However...

Presence of force implies energy exchange, whether it is in its explicit form (i.e. a stone falling from the cliff) or implicit (i.e. friction force from the previous answer). A state of philosophical understanding of force these days, as far as I get it, is that any force is mediated by agents: photons, gravitons, gluons etc. These particles carry some form of energy with them and "deliver" it from "sender" to the "recipient", so to say. If one thinks about it this way, there is always some kind of field (potential) present, that mediates interaction. At this point it is the question about definitions, not actual phenomena...

P.S.: in the case of friction, this field is electrostatic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Friction is a great example of a force that doesn't have a well defined potential energy field associated with it. You can pull some strings and a create a faux potential (see Rayleigh dissipation function) to derive the frictional force from, but it doesn't behave the way a real potential would.